# How to compare two table columns and insert it into new table stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I am new to SQL Server. I want to create a procedure which should check two tables and insert the different rows into another table. I need some code example thanks in advance. And if the row is same do not insert else insert.

`Table1` is like

```
username product shippeddate
Muha     car1     15.08.2014
```

`Table2` is like

```
username product shippedate
Muha      car1
```

Comment: How do you know which rows from those tables to compare? Is there a common column or something?

Comment: actually there is a text file which contains the whole table data, i can insert the whole file into a table but i have to compare the existing records and insert the different rows comming from a text file

Comment: Confused - what exactly are you trying to do?? You want to import the text file into a temporary table, and compare against `Table1`, and insert those rows that don't already exist in `Table1` ? Your question said something about *insert the different rows into another table* - what now??

Comment: Now , I have a file which is updating every week, lets say this week there are 100 rows in that file and next week 50 more added now when it was 100 i have added that file data into table but next week more 50 rows came, but the file contain 100 + 50 rows so file have old data in it i want to insert only new data into a table.

Answer (score 1):

Even you can use the "Except" operator to compare 2 result set and insert the output.

```
select * from table1
except
select * from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the point of this is to review the differences between the two tables, you could add a unique index to both and use Data Compare from SSDT to compare them.  This would give you a visual representation of the differences and even generate a script to update a target table if you wished.

you can get SSDT here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh297027.aspx
Once installed, Go to SQL > Data Compare > New Data Comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
declare @table1 table (username varchar(10), product varchar(10), shippeddate datetime)
declare @table2 table (username varchar(10), product varchar(10), shippeddate datetime)

insert into @table1
select 'Muha','car1','2014-08-15' union
select 'Steve','car2','2014-08-12' 

insert into @table2
select 'Muha','car1',null

insert into @table1
select t2.*
from @table2 t2
left outer join @table1 t1
   on isnull(t1.username,'') = isnull(t2.username,'')
   and isnull(t1.product,'') = isnull(t2.product,'')
   and t1.shippeddate = t2.shippeddate
where t1.username is null

select * from @table1
```

Here is a second example using `NOT EXISTS`.

```
declare @table1 table (username varchar(10), product varchar(10), shippeddate datetime)
declare @table2 table (username varchar(10), product varchar(10), shippeddate datetime)

insert into @table1
select 'Muha','car1','2014-08-15' union
select 'Steve','car2','2014-08-12' 

insert into @table2
select 'Muha','car1',null

insert into @table1
select t2.*
from @table2 t2
where not exists (select * from @table1 t1 where isnull(t1.username,'')=isnull(t2.username,'') and isnull(t1.product,'')=isnull(t2.product,'') and t1.shippeddate=t2.shippeddate)

select * from @table1
```

In both cases you need to be cognizant of NULL values, as they do not evaluate as equal using `=`.  I left the date comparison without a null handler intentionally in both scenarios -- you would need to decide based on your business rules how they should be treated.